# Error on using TransactionScope in EF4 & SQL Compact 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var context = new dwfEntities())
{
  var field = (from x in context.DynFields where x.Id == id select x).First();

  //delete defaults
  foreach (var item in from x in context.DynFieldDefaults where x.DynField_Id == id select x)
  {
    context.DeleteObject(item);
  }
  context.SaveChanges();

  //delete field
  context.DeleteObject(field);
  context.SaveChanges();

  //commit
  scope.Complete();
}
```

The code throws "The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope"

Does SQL CE 4 support TransactionScope ? if not, is there any workaround so I can safely delete objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in case SQL CE does not support transaction scope, you can surely use the normal transactional approach, connection.BeginTransaction then transaction.Commit or Rollback...

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is opened outside of the transaction scope you need to explicitly call EnlistTransaction. You cannot implicitly use a connection with a transaction scope in SQL CE as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896149%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)